# Two equivalent definitions of complete reducibility of a group representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, definition, lie-groups

Consider two definitions of complete reducibility of a group representation.

**Definition 1**

A representation $\,A\,$ is completely reducible if it splits into a direct sum of irreducibles.

**Definition 2**

A representation $\,A\,$ is completely reducible if any of its subrepresentations has a complementary subrepresentation.

To prove these definitions' equivalence, consider three separate cases.

1. $A\,$ is reducible, and the dimensions are infinite. This case is nontrivial and requires Zorn's lemma. Let us not go there.
2. $A\,$ is reducible, and the dimensions are finite. This is an easy exercise.
3. $A\,$ is irreducible. This case requires some attention.

On the one hand, the case of an irreducible $A$ obviously falls under the auspices of Definition 1. Indeed, $A$ splits into a sum of irreducibles -- and the sum contains only one summand, $A$ itself. So, by Definition 1, an irreducible $A$ is completely reducible.

On the other hand, it is not apparently obvious how to show that Definition 2 remains equivalent to Definition 1 in this case. For $A$ irreducible, its only subrepresentations are $A$ itself and $0$. Can we say that $A$ and $0$ are complement to one another? If yes, then we are alright. I am unsure though, because the zero vector is a subspace of the representation space of $A$. So can it really be regarded as complement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A complement of a subspace $W$ of a vector space $V$ is a subspace $W'$ such that $V=W\bigoplus W'$ (that is, such that $V=W+W'$ and that $W\cap W'=\{0\}$). So, yes, $V$ itself is a complement of $\{0\}$ and $\{0\}$ is a complement of $V$.

Comment: Thank you. I see that my understanding of complement was not clear enough.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.